# MySQL installation question

Tags: mysql, installation, ssd

I am far from a DBA and have a question.  Recently I installed MySQL.  On my machine C:\ is a 50GB partition of two mirrored 10k SAS drives.  The remaining space on those drives is allocated to D:.  I also have a SSD mounted as E:.  When I installed MySQL, I installed it to E:\ assuming that that is where the database information would be held since I had installed it there.  I am now seeing C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\data\peq, peq being the name of my main database.  Is my database being stored in C:\ and if so, how do I fix it to store the DB on the SSD?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the datadir in my.cnf
Stop mysql, edit my.cnf, move your datadir to the new location, restart mysql,
that should be it :)

Comment: please reformat!